# Loading webview within application

Tags: android

I am trying to load a web page within my application.

I have added the permission

In the xml layout I add the webview within my Relative Layout:

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250px"
         android:layout_marginTop="80px"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
/>
```

I then call this within a button:

```
 WebView MyWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);        
                        MyWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        MyWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

But this opens a new browser within my application when I want it to only open it within the height and width.

Thanks

Edit: Forget this, it works now, I have moved my whole application to a new one and it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xml file

```
  <WebView

  android:id="@+id/webfashion"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  />
```

It was not working for me when i was not using **fill_parent** for the width and height
-Ted